# How to `SELECT` and manufacture missing rows from previous values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following (simplified) result from `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY tick,refid`:

```
tick refid value
----------------
1    1     11
1    2     22
1    3     33
2    1     1111
2    3     3333
3    3     333333
```

Note the "missing" rows for refid 1 (tick 3) and refid 2 (ticks 2 and 3)

If possible, how can I make a query to add these missing rows using the most recent prior `value` for that `refid`? "Most recent" means the value for the row with the same refid as the missing row and largest tick such that the tick is less than the tick for the missing row. e.g.

```
tick refid value
----------------
1    1     11
1    2     22
1    3     33
2    1     1111
2    2     22
2    3     3333
3    1     1111
3    2     22
3    3     333333
```

Additional conditions:

- All refids will have values at tick=1.
- There may be many 'missing' ticks for a refid in sequence, (as above for refid 2).
- There are many refids and it's not known which will have sparse data where.
- There will be many ticks beyond 3, but all sequential. In the correct result, each refid will have a result for each tick.
- Missing rows are not known in advance - this will be run on multiple databases, all with the same structure, and different "missing" rows.

I'm using MySQL and cannot change db just now. Feel free to post answer in another dialect, to help discussion, but I'll select an answer in MySQL dialect over others.

Yes, I know this can be done in the code, which I've implemented. I'm just curious if it can be done with SQL.

Comment: By "most recent", do you mean the `value` for the row with the same `refid` as the missing row and largest `tick` such that the `tick` is < the `tick` for the missing row? Are there any `tick`s that are entirely missing (i.e. that do not occur at all in the table) and need to be added?

Comment: @outis correct on definition of "most recent" `value`. I believe there _could_ be `tick`s eitirely missing (though I've not seen it in the wild)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `value` should be returned when a given tick-refid combination does not exist? In this solution, I simply returned the lowest value for that given refid.

**Revision**

I've updated the logic to determine what value to use in the case of a null. It should be noted that I'm assuming that ticks+refid is unique in the table.

```
Select Ticks.tick
    , Refs.refid
    , Case
        When Table.value Is Null 
            Then    (
                    Select T2.value
                    From Table As T2
                    Where T2.refid = Refs.refId
                        And T2.tick =  (
                                        Select Max(T1.tick)
                                        From Table As T1
                                        Where T1.tick < Ticks.tick
                                            And T1.refid = T2.refid
                                        )
                    )
        Else Table.value
        End As value
From    (
        Select Distinct refid
        From Table
        ) As Refs
    Cross Join  (
                Select Distinct tick
                From Table
                ) As Ticks
    Left Join Table
        On Table.tick = Ticks.tick
            And Table.refid = Refs.refid
```

Comment: The value inserted into the missing rows should be the most recent (based on ordered ticks) seen for that refid. See the example for refid=1.

Comment: @Chadwick - Suppose I'm working on tick 743 and it's missing refid 32. Now suppose tick 740 has a value for refid 32 and tick 744 has a value for refid 32. Do I use the one from tick 740?

Comment: @Chadwick - Also, is there is a single integer primary key on this table?

Comment: in that scenario, tick 743, refid 32 would be given the same value as tick 740, _not_ tick 744.

Comment: @Chadwick - Ok. Then I think my amended solution should do the trick

Comment: Based on `EXPLAIN`, this query has the best performance of those posted thus far.

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance what your 'tick' and 'refid' values are,

1. Make a helper table that contains all possible tick and refid values.
2. Then left join from the helper table on tick and refid to your data table.

If you don't know exactly what your 'tick' and 'refid' values are, you maybe could still use this method, but instead of a static helper table, it would have to be dynamically generated.

Comment: It will not be known which rows will be missing. Edited the question to include this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the list of pairs (tick, refid) to insert get a whole list:

```
     SELECT a.tick, b.refid
       FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT tick  FROM t) a
 CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT refid FROM t) b
```

Now substract from that query the existing ones:

```
     SELECT a.tick tick, b.refid refid
       FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT tick  FROM t) a
 CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT refid FROM t) b
 MINUS
     SELECT DISTINCT tick, refid FROM t
```

Now you can join with t to obtain the final query (note that I use inner join + left join to obtain previous result but you could adapt):

```
INSERT INTO t(tick, refid, value)
SELECT c.tick, c.refid, t1.value
  FROM (        SELECT a.tick tick, b.refid refid
                  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT tick  FROM t) a
            CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT refid FROM t) b
            MINUS
                SELECT DISTINCT tick, refid FROM t
       ) c
 INNER JOIN t t1 ON t1.refid = c.refid and t1.tick < c.tick
  LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t2.refid = c.refid AND t1.tick < t2.tick AND t2.tick < c.tick
 WHERE t2.tick IS NULL
```

Comment: Though this approach may work in other RDBMSs, MySQL doesn't support `MINUS`. Derived table `c` has no `value` column; did you mean `t1.value`? Also, it appears you've swapped `tick` and `refid` in your join clauses against t1 and t2.

Answer (score 0):

The following has too many sub-selects for my taste, but it generates the desired result in MySQL, as long as every tick and every refid occurs separately at least once in the table.

Start with a query that generates every pair of tick and refid. The following uses the table to generate the pairs, so if any tick never appears in the underlying table, it will also be missing from the generated pairs. The same holds true for refids, though the restriction that "All refids will have values at tick=1" should ensure the latter never happens.

```
SELECT tick, refid FROM
  (SELECT refid FROM chadwick WHERE tick=1) AS r
  JOIN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT tick FROM chadwick) AS t
```

Using this, generate every missing tick, refid pair, along with the largest tick that exists in the table by equijoining on refid and θ<sub>≥</sub>-joining on tick. Group by the generated tick, refid since only one row for each pair is desired. The key to filtering out existing tick, refid pairs is the `HAVING` clause. Strictly speaking, you can leave out the `HAVING`; the resulting query will return existing rows with their existing values.

```
SELECT tr.tick, tr.refid, MAX(c.tick) AS ctick
  FROM 
      (SELECT tick, refid FROM
        (SELECT refid FROM chadwick WHERE tick=1) AS r
        JOIN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT tick FROM chadwick) AS t
      ) AS tr
  JOIN chadwick AS c ON tr.tick >= c.tick AND tr.refid=c.refid
  GROUP BY tr.tick, tr.refid
  HAVING tr.tick > MAX(c.tick)
```

One final select from the above as a sub-select, joined to the original table to get the value for the given ctick, returns the new rows for the table.

```
INSERT INTO chadwick
SELECT missing.tick, missing.refid, c.value
  FROM (SELECT tr.tick, tr.refid, MAX(c.tick) AS ctick
    FROM 
      (SELECT tick, refid FROM
        (SELECT refid FROM chadwick WHERE tick=1) AS r
        JOIN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT tick FROM chadwick) AS t
      ) AS tr
    JOIN chadwick AS c ON tr.tick >= c.tick AND tr.refid=c.refid
    GROUP BY tr.tick, tr.refid
  ) AS missing
  JOIN chadwick AS c ON missing.ctick = c.tick AND missing.refid=c.refid
;
```

Performance on the sample table, along with `(tick, refid)` and `(refid, tick)` indices:

> ```
> +----+-------------+------------+-------+-------------------+----------+---------+----------+------+---------------------------------+
> | id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys     | key      | key_len | ref      | rows | Extra                           |
> +----+-------------+------------+-------+-------------------+----------+---------+----------+------+---------------------------------+
> |  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL              | NULL     | NULL    | NULL     |    3 |                                 |
> |  1 | PRIMARY     | c          | ALL   | tick_ref,ref_tick | NULL     | NULL    | NULL     |    6 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
> |  2 | DERIVED     | <derived3> | ALL   | NULL              | NULL     | NULL    | NULL     |    9 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
> |  2 | DERIVED     | c          | ref   | tick_ref,ref_tick | ref_tick | 5       | tr.refid |    1 | Using where; Using index        |
> |  3 | DERIVED     | <derived4> | ALL   | NULL              | NULL     | NULL    | NULL     |    3 |                                 |
> |  3 | DERIVED     | <derived5> | ALL   | NULL              | NULL     | NULL    | NULL     |    3 | Using join buffer               |
> |  5 | DERIVED     | chadwick   | index | NULL              | tick_ref | 10      | NULL     |    6 | Using index                     |
> |  4 | DERIVED     | chadwick   | ref   | tick_ref          | tick_ref | 5       |          |    2 | Using where; Using index        |
> +----+-------------+------------+-------+-------------------+----------+---------+----------+------+---------------------------------+
> ```

As I said, too many sub-selects. A temporary table may help matters.

To check for missing ticks:

```
SELECT clo.tick+1 AS missing_tick
  FROM chadwick AS chi
    RIGHT JOIN chadwick AS clo ON chi.tick = clo.tick+1
  WHERE chi.tick IS NULL;
```

This will return at least one row with tick equal to 1 + the largest tick in the table. Thus, the largest value in this result can be ignored.